# Stack like effect in SliverAppBar

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm need to somehow move the `ClipRRect` from the `SliverToBoxAdapter` up so it stack over the bottom of the top `Hero`. I don't know how to do that in the `SliverAppBar`.

```
slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            expandedHeight: 300,
            backgroundColor: Color(0xff151825),
            elevation: 0,
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              collapseMode: CollapseMode.parallax,
              background: Hero(
                tag: 'location-name',
                child: ShaderMask(
                  shaderCallback: (rect) {
                    return LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      colors: [Color(0xff151825), Colors.transparent],
                    ).createShader(
                        Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, rect.width, rect.height));
                  },
                  blendMode: BlendMode.dstIn,
                  child: Image.network(
                    'https://placeimg.com/640/480/any',
                    height: 350,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(90.0),
                          child: Image.network(
                            "https:...",
                            height: 100.0,
                            width: 100.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to change it like this.

```
   background: Hero(
            tag: 'location-name',
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                ShaderMask(
                  shaderCallback: (rect) {
                    return LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      colors: [Color(0xff151825), Colors.transparent],
                    ).createShader(
                        Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, rect.width, rect.height));
                  },
                  blendMode: BlendMode.dstIn,
                  child: Image.network(
                    'https://placeimg.com/640/480/any',
                    height: 350,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(90.0),
                    child: Image.network(
                      "https:...",
                      height: 130.0,
                      width: 130.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
```